# shorthand for `extends Foo[keyof Foo]`

Tags: typescript

Assuming I have some types:

```
type A = { a : string };
type B = { b : string };
```

and an interface with properties, where each property is a type:

```
interface Foo {
  a: A;
  b: B;
}
```

and now I have function with a generic:

```
function foo<K extends Foo[keyof Foo]>(arg : K) : K {...}
```

is there a way to write `K extends Foo[keyof Foo]` in a shorter way? Like something like `K extends property of Foo`? At least something that does not force me to write `Foo` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own generic type for this

```
type Properties<T> = T[keyof T]
```

and then use it like this

```
function foo<K extends Properties<Foo>>(arg: K): K
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an alias to `Foo` property types:

```
type FooProps = Foo[keyof Foo];
function foo<K extends FooProps>(arg: K): K { ... };
```